# take a part and take part the difference

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could you explain the difference between «take a part in » and «take part in»?
For example I took a part in a show and I took part in a show.

Thank you!

Comment: Looking up [*part*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/part) in a dictionary would probably help. In *took a part*, *part* means **role**; in *took part in*, *part* means **shared**.

Comment: To _take part in_ means to participate in some group action; no specific role is assumed. To _take a part in_ can mean to play a part in a drama, or simply have or take up a specific job or status in some group activity, perhaps ongoing -- in any event, a personal rather than a group distinction.